# .click() only firing once then no more after that unless i refresh the whole page and doesn't render at all if i call $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to retrieve a quote and its author from a JSON file, the problem I am having is that once I click the button once, then the event is fired but only once and no more after that. Equally, when I call $(document).ready() the button doesn't fire at all.

I know that it is something to do with the way I am collecting the data from the JSON file (is an array of objects with text, author keys), and then subsequently calling the fetch when I want to retrieve a new quote with the correct author.

```js
// https://type.fit/api/quotes //
// api link for quotes //
const button = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const baseUrl = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

function getQuote() {
 fetch(baseUrl)
  fetch(baseUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quote => $('#text-output').text(quote[randomNumber].text))
   };

function getAuthor() {
  fetch(baseUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quote => $('#author').text(quote[randomNumber].author))
};

function renderQuoteToPage() {
  getQuote();
  getAuthor();
}


$('#new-quote').click(renderQuoteToPage);
$(document).ready(renderQuoteToPage);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-wrapper" class="container-fluid">

<div id="quote-box" class="card w-50">
  <div class="card-body">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
  <div id="text">
    <p id="text-output"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      <a href="#" id="tweet-quote">Tweet</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
      <div id="author">Author</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
  <button id="new-quote">New quote</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: _"Can view the pen on codepen..."_ - Please add a [mcve] **in the question itself** (preferable as [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) and not only a link to an external resource that might not be available for whatever reason -> [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the functions when you attach the handlers, so they are invoked without the appropriate handler being attached, and just once.

You need just the function definition:

```
$('#new-quote').click(renderQuoteToPage);
...
$(document).ready(renderQuoteOnPageLoad);
```

**Edit:** You also need to set `randomNumber` on each `getQuote()` call

```js
// https://type.fit/api/quotes //
// api link for quotes //
const button = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const baseUrl = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';
let randomNumber

function getQuote() {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  fetch(baseUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(quote => $('#text-output').text(quote[randomNumber].text))
};

function getAuthor() {
  fetch(baseUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(quote => $('#author').text(quote[randomNumber].author))
};

function renderQuoteToPage() {
  getQuote();
  getAuthor();
}


$('#new-quote').click(renderQuoteToPage);
$(document).ready(renderQuoteToPage);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-wrapper" class="container-fluid">

  <div id="quote-box" class="card w-50">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="text">
            <p id="text-output"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#" id="tweet-quote">Tweet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="author">Author</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button id="new-quote">New quote</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but still having the same issue.

Comment: You've defined `let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);` at the beginning, so its the same for every call and you get the same quote. You need to set it on each `getQuote()` call. Check the edit to answer

Answer (score 1):

Few changes in your script and its done.

```
<script>
const button = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const baseUrl = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';
let randomNumber;

function getQuote() {
  fetch(baseUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quote => $('#text-output').text(quote[randomNumber].text))
   };

function getAuthor() {
  fetch(baseUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(quote => $('#author').text(quote[randomNumber].author))
};

function renderQuoteOnPageLoad() {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  getQuote();
  getAuthor();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    renderQuoteOnPageLoad();
});

 $(document).on("click","#new-quote",function(){
    renderQuoteOnPageLoad()
 })
</script>
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyrqmnwf/)